# How can I append text and an output to a button?

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a program that I'm writing to scan barcodes.

Right now, I can get the output from the reader to show up in the button.  This is what the code looks like:

```
decodeCallback = DecodeCallback {
            runOnUiThread {
                binding.button.text= it.text
            }
        }
```

What I want it to say though is this:

"Search For:

*foo*"

All inside the button.

I am really new to kotlin so I'm struggling with this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need `runOnUiThread` because callbacks typically are automatically called on the UI thread already.

You can use a String template to fill a term into a String:

```kotlin
decodeCallback = DecodeCallback {
    binding.button.text= "Search For: ${it.text}"
}
```

If you're on Android, you should use String resources so your user-facing strings are all defined in one place and you can do translations later easily. In your resources you would have something like this, where you use a Java format string.

```xml
<string name="searchButtonLabel">Search For: %s</string>
```

And then use

```kotlin
decodeCallback = DecodeCallback {
    binding.button.text = getString(R.string.searchButtonLabel, it.text)
}
```

If this is in a Fragment, you'd use `requireContext().getString(`.

Comment: The first part worked beautifully.  I don't quite understand the <string name = part.  Very new to programming but I am on Android.

Also, appreciate the time you took to answer.  Thank you!

Comment: And I just googled it and now I get it!  Thank you so much!